# To show analyticity, is it enough to show just differentiability?

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:** Suppose $h(z)$ is a continuous function on a curve $\gamma$. Show that $$H(w)=\int_{\gamma} \frac{h(z)}{z-w} dz$$, where $w \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \gamma$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \gamma$.

I found an answer at the last page of this link: http://people.ucalgary.ca/~mwgirard/coursework/CompAna/ComplexAnalysis_Quiz2.pdf

But I am not sure why it has not been proven that $H'(w)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \gamma$.
Also, I am not sure the author just assumed that $h(z)$ is analytic, when it is just given to be continuous.

Comment: @EricWofsey 
"Note that $h(z)$ is bounded on $\gamma$, since $\gamma$ is bounded and $h(z)$ is analytic on $\gamma$". We were just given that $h(z)$ is continuous on $\gamma$.

Comment: Oh, I somehow missed that.  I think that's just a typo and it should say continuous instead.

Answer (score 1):

If $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is an open set and $H:U\to\mathbb{C}$ is a function which has a complex derivative at every point, then $H$ is analytic.  It is not necessary to assume the derivative of $H$ is continuous, since that actually follows automatically. (Indeed, the very problem you are asking about is closely related to the proof that the derivative is automatically continuous.  If $\gamma$ is a circle and $h$ happens to be analytic on the disk bounded by $\gamma$, then $H=h$ on that disk by the Cauchy integral formula.  Using the method of the problem to not just differentiate $H$ but differentiate it twice, we find that $H'$ is differentiable and hence continuous, so $h'$ is continuous.)

The statement in the link you gave that $h(z)$ is analytic is presumably just a misstatement and it should instead say that $h(z)$ is continuous.  All that is being used here is that $h$ is bounded on $\gamma$, which follows from just continuity.

Answer (score 0):

The function $H(w)=\oint_{\gamma}\frac{h(z)}{z-w}dz$ is continuous in the interior of $\gamma$. Furthermore, if $\Delta$ is a triangle contained in the interior of $\gamma$, then
$$
   \oint_{\Delta}H(w)dw = \oint_{\Delta}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{h(z)}{z-w}dzdw \\
     = \oint_{\gamma}\oint_{\Delta}\frac{1}{z-w}dwh(z)dz \\
     = \oint_{\gamma}0\cdot h(z)dz = 0.
$$
Therefore $H$ is holomorphic by Morera's Theorem. And
$$
   H'(w)=\oint_{\gamma}\frac{h(z)}{(z-w)^2}dz,\;\;\; w\in\mbox{Int}(\gamma).
$$
There is no reason to assume that $\lim_{w\rightarrow w_0}H'(w)$ exist if $w_0$ is on $\gamma$.